# Give [jison] a higher tag priority than [javascript]

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

Recently I asked a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201668/creating-a-new-language-freezeflame) and created the new tag [jison](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jison). I also tagged the question with [javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) because that is what the language compiles to. However, I noticed that the title in the browser was prefixed with `javascript -` which I believe should be changed to `jison -`, as the primary code is written in the language Jison. Excuse me if tag priority cannot be changed, but I believe this is a bug and should be fixed.

Comment: IIRC it takes the most popular tag, rather than a 'language' tag.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Than in this case, should I not tag the question with [tag:javascript]

Comment: I wouldn't as the question doesn't seem to have anything to do with JavaScript. And following your train of thought we should tag all C/C++ questions with assembly... But then it'd use a different tag rather than JavaScript so still wouldn't solve this problem.

Comment: related https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8902/162379

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I looked and I don't think that we can change the hierarchy of the tags because they are based on SO's tag system.

My guess is that if you posted on their meta about it for their site, that you may be able to get it changed. But I'm not sure about the whole process.

Something else that should be discussed is the syntax highlighting. If it is close enough to JavaScript I could set that for the tag, but think it would only apply on Code Review.

Comment: The syntax for Jison is very close to that of YACC as opposed to JS

Comment: I don't think SO have a pre-defined 'what's a language list', look at the question now, it says 'compiler' is the language as it's the most popular tag on the question.

Comment: If the syntax highlighter for CR uses vim, I think I could get a vim file for Jison

Comment: if I remember right they use google prettify or something like that, and just reference it.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Odd behavior. It's also the first tag listed - could that be what it is?

Comment: It looks like it's using the correct one anyhow. Somehow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting  here is the SO highlighting

Comment: And here's a [meta about the tag title selection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153455)

Answer (score 9):

To make [jison](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jison) be in the title [it has to be the most popular tag on the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153455). Since it has one question you'd have to remove all the other tags, which I'd advise against.

As Malachi has mentioned syntax highlighting, this mechanism works separately to this tag title selection. In short it's bound to a tag.

---

They may both interact if there are two tags with syntax highlighting are used, and I'd assume it's the most popular tag that it'd use. [But you can set a different default in the question if you want](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting):

> ```
> <!-- language-all: lang -->
> ```

Comment: No, if you have two tags with conflicting syntax-highlighting-preference, it simply uses `default` instead of either.